# Prove that $\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab}\ge 2$ for all positive integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

How would you prove that $\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab}\ge2$ is true for all positive integers $a$ and $b$? I can easily prove that $a\ge1$, $b\ge1$ (so $a^2+b^2\ge2$) and $ab\ge1$.

Would you do it by proving that $a^2$ increases "quicker" than $a$ does and therefore the lowest that $\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab}\ge2$ could be is when $a=1,b=1$ which gives the result as 2? Thanks.

(Sorry if that's badly worded.)

Comment: Hint: $(a-b)^2$.

Comment: Start with $(a-b)^2\geq 0$

Comment: Do you know how to prove $a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$?

Comment: Yes I see now thank you. I probably should have seen that myself. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a>0$ and $b>0$, then $ab>0$, so we can multiply both sides with $ab$.
$$a^2+b^2\ge 2ab\\a^2+b^2-2ab\ge0\\(a-b)^2\ge 0$$The last expression is true, no matter what $a$ or $b$ you choose. It also tells that you have the equality when $a=b$

Comment: It's bad practice to start with the conclusion you want and derive a true statement, even if (in this particular case) it's valid because the steps are reversible.

Comment: Thanks @MishaLavrov. That's true. I would have done it differently if the problem was not formulated as "prove that..."

Answer (score 2):

Since  $(a-b)^2\geq 0$, $a^2-2ab+b^2\geq 0$. So $a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$. Dividing by $ab$ we get your request.